# JS - Сложение значений в тегах

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, интересует вот какой вопрос, например у меня есть 4 поля, 2 из них, откуда переносим объекты и 2 куда из собственно вносим (Спасибо огромное Grundy). Нужно выполнить операции сложения и вычитания чисел, находящихся в тегах `<p></p>`, пробовал вот этот код внедрить всеми вариантами:

```
var sum = 0;
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('itemprice');
addTrade.call(this, items, dest);
$(this).children('p').attr("class", "itemprice");
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        sum += Number(text[i].innerHTML);
    }
console.log('Итого', sum);
document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 'Итого: ' + sum;
```

Но в итоге получалось только одностороннее сложение и вычитание, то есть когда нажимаем на item в желтом поле, идет прибавление, когда нажимаем на него в оранжевом - идет вычитание, а нужно, чтобы перенося из верхнего желтого блока в верхний оранжевый, шло прибавление к общей сумме, а перенося из нижнего желтого блока в нижний оранжевый, от этой суммы отнималось от общей суммы, а перенося все обратно в желтое, естественно все наоборот. + чтобы начальная сумма была равна числу в другом блоке, вот пример:

```js
var useritems = [];
var botitems = [];

function addTrade(items, dest) {
  if (items.length < 10) {
    items.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    $(this).appendTo(dest);
  }
}

function removetrade(items, dest) {
  items.splice(items.indexOf($(this).attr('data-id')), 1);
  $(this).appendTo(dest);
}

function addRemoveInit(items, src, dest) {
  $(src).on('click', '.item', function() {
    addTrade.call(this, items, dest);
  });
  $(dest).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removetrade.call(this, items, src);
  });
}
addRemoveInit(useritems, '.inventoryload', '.tradehave');
addRemoveInit(botitems, '.botinventoryload', '.tradewant');

function tradesend() {
  if (useritems.length > 0) {
    var data_post = reduceItems(botitems, 'h', reduceItems(useritems, 'w', {}));
    console.log(data_post);
  }
}

function reduceItems(items, prefix, start) {
  return items.reduce(function(acc, el, index) {
    acc[prefix + (index + 1)] = el;
    return acc;
  }, start);
}
```

```css
.inventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
.botinventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
.tradewant {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
.tradehave {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
.inv {
  float: left;
}
.trade {
  float: left;
}
.balance {
  width: 302px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
  }
.price {
  width: 302px;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid;}
.item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 2px;}
li {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="balance">Баланс: <span>322</span></p>
<div class="inv">
  <div class="inventoryload">
    <li class="item" data-id="1111"><p>2141</p></li>
    <li class="item" data-id="1251"><p>212</p></li>
    <li class="item" data-id="4444"><p>4574</p></li>
  </div>
  <div class="botinventoryload">
    <li class="item" data-id="3251"><p>11</p></li>
    <li class="item" data-id="8018"><p>175</p></li>
    <li class="item" data-id="6543"><p>653</p></li>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="trade">
  <div class="tradehave">
  </div>
  <div class="tradewant">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="info" style="float:left; width: 199px; padding-left: 10px">
  Тут при переносе элемента из желтого в оранжевое поле должно быть прибавление числа в нем к общей сумме "Итого:", при обратном, должно быть отнимание числа от общей суммы
  <br>---------------------<br>
  Тут при переносе из желтого в оранжевое поле должно быть отнимание числа в нем от общей суммы "Итого:", при переносе обратно, должно быть прибавление числа к общей сумме
  <br>---------------------<br>
  "Итого:" + "Баланс:"
  </div>
<p class="price">Итого: <span>322</span></p>
<button onClick="tradesend();" id="button">Обменять</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так как в момент переноса известны все необходимые данные для добавления/отнимания из итога, эту операцию можно делать внутри функций `add-/remove-trade`

```
function addTrade(items, dest, coef) {
  if (items.length < 10) {
    items.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    $(this).appendTo(dest);
    updatePrice(Number($(this).text())*coef);
  }
}
```

Где *updatePrice* - функция непосредственно ответственная за обновление поля

```
function updatePrice(price){
  var priceEl = $('.price span'); //элемент в котором выводится конечная цена
  priceEl.html(Number(priceEl.html())+price);
}
```

Так как от области зависит добавлять или отнимать, можно регулировать это за счет параметра `coef` при вызове соответствующей функции.

Пример в сборе:

```js
var useritems = [];
var botitems = [];

function addTrade(items, dest, coef) {
  if (items.length < 10) {
    items.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
    $(this).appendTo(dest);
    updatePrice(Number($(this).text()) * coef);
  }
}

function removetrade(items, dest, coef) {
  items.splice(items.indexOf($(this).attr('data-id')), 1);
  $(this).appendTo(dest);
  updatePrice(Number($(this).text()) * coef);
}

function addRemoveInit(items, src, dest, coef) {
  $(src).on('click', '.item', function() {
    addTrade.call(this, items, dest, coef);
  });
  $(dest).on('click', '.item', function() {
    removetrade.call(this, items, src, -coef);
  });
}
addRemoveInit(useritems, '.inventoryload', '.tradehave', 1);
addRemoveInit(botitems, '.botinventoryload', '.tradewant', -1);

function tradesend() {
  if (useritems.length > 0) {
    var data_post = reduceItems(botitems, 'h', reduceItems(useritems, 'w', {}));
    console.log(data_post);
  }
}

function reduceItems(items, prefix, start) {
  return items.reduce(function(acc, el, index) {
    acc[prefix + (index + 1)] = el;
    return acc;
  }, start);
}

function updatePrice(price) {
  var priceEl = $('.price span'); //элемент в котором выводится конечная цена
  priceEl.html(Number(priceEl.html()) + price);
}
```

```css
.inventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
.botinventoryload {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
.tradewant {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
.tradehave {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
.inv {
  float: left;
}
.trade {
  float: left;
}
.balance {
  width: 302px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
}
.price {
  width: 302px;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
}
li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="balance">Баланс: <span>322</span>
</p>
<div class="inv">
  <div class="inventoryload">
    <li class="item" data-id="1111">
      <p>2141</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item" data-id="1251">
      <p>212</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item" data-id="4444">
      <p>4574</p>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="botinventoryload">
    <li class="item" data-id="3251">
      <p>11</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item" data-id="8018">
      <p>175</p>
    </li>
    <li class="item" data-id="6543">
      <p>653</p>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="trade">
  <div class="tradehave">
  </div>
  <div class="tradewant">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="info" style="float:left; width: 199px; padding-left: 10px">
  Тут при переносе элемента из желтого в оранжевое поле должно быть прибавление числа в нем к общей сумме "Итого:", при обратном, должно быть отнимание числа от общей суммы
  <br>---------------------
  <br>Тут при переносе из желтого в оранжевое поле должно быть отнимание числа в нем от общей суммы "Итого:", при переносе обратно, должно быть прибавление числа к общей сумме
  <br>---------------------
  <br>"Итого:" + "Баланс:"
</div>
<p class="price">Итого: <span>322</span>
</p>
<button onClick="tradesend();" id="button">Обменять</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, не догадался использовать умножение на -1 и 1

Comment: @100РОЖЬ, умножение необязательно, просто как один из способов обобщить поведение